# Update observable array property when a different observable is changed

Tags: knockout.js

I have a "locale" observable that is basically just a JS object that contains locale-specific strings. I also have a tabs observable array, which contains multiple properties, one of which is a title that is populated by a locale value.

e.g.

```
this.tabs = ko.observableArray([{
    title: this.locale().tabs.one
}, {
    title: this.locale().tabs.two
}]);
```

Here is a JSFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/robgallen/v64p2/

I am trying to figure out the best strategy to get the tab titles to change when the locale observable is changed.

I have tried using knockout mapping but this doesn't seem to help. I have also tried adding a ko.observableArray.fn.refresh to update the data within the tabs array, but it simply uses the original tabs data, rather than referring back to the locale data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about the answers here, particularly Chuck's, this is about the best I could come up with:

http://jsfiddle.net/robgallen/v64p2/3/

Adding a subscription that re-populates the tabs array, using a key to lookup the changed locale string:

```
self.locale.subscribe(function (data) {
    var newTabs = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.tabs(), function(tab) {
        tab.title = data.tabs[tab.key];
        newTabs.push(tab);
    });
    self.tabs(null);
    self.tabs(newTabs);
});
```

Not great and I realise I might not be thinking about this in the correct manner. Luckily most of the localisation is done in the html view and this works fine.

Answer (score 1):

How about this instead? [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F7CKk/2/)

```
<ul data-bind="with: locale">
     <li data-bind="text: tabs.one"></li>
    <li data-bind="text: tabs.two"></li>
</ul>
```

Or this [update](http://jsfiddle.net/Aa27d/2/) to rwisch45's fiddle works too

Comment: tabs is a far more complicated object than I have indicated in my example. It contains multiple properties, one of which is the localised title. My bad. I don't think I can just rewrite it from scratch.

Comment: Although I will look into calling a helper function to return a new tabs object, with the new localised values as per your 2nd fiddle.

Comment: Check out this fiddle on translations using knockout: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/hJL6h/). Maybe that will give you further ideas. :-) I suspected that your example was a simplification of your problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use a client-side i18n solution such as [i18next](http://i18next.com/).  The problem with allowing a user to dynamically change the locale is that it will lead to an enormously complex UI.  Text that would otherwise be boilerplate--for example, field labels, tabs, etc.--would need to be observable in order to respond to an observable change in your locale (most likely in a configuration module).  That configurable observable would have to be injected into every module in order to drive the observable changes in locale.

We tried the approach you're taking and found that it weighed us down burdensomely.  We opted for something unobtrusive, something that didn't require observables everywhere just for the sake of conveying a language change.

@rwisch45 suggests *subscribe*, which will work--and work well--for a small solution.  But subscribe won't scale well.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. locale is actually an observable that i18next returns. It works fine with data-bind attributes, but not directly in another observableArray, as shown.

Comment: I too have now found out that the overhead was getting massive. I could translate the labels and any observable arrays on the fly, but I also had to refresh data from the server and set & refresh locale for any other components, e.g. momentjs, kendo. Most users will actually just login in one language, so the overhead wasn't acceptable.

Comment: @SpaceMonkey Glad I could help. Sometimes you just have to travel down a path to see where it goes :).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `subscribe` (see [explicitly subscribing to observables in the KO docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables)) to know whenever the value of the `locale` has changed. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/Aa27d/). The following observable subscription in your view model will fire off every time that the value of `locale` is changed. You can put your own custom logic inside the function.

```
self.locale.subscribe(function(){
   alert('locale changed');
});
```

Comment: It's the custom logic I need help with, not the subscribe.